# Stop animation after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two buttons that control the image above, and they basically change the image in the forward direction or reverse direction. My code is as follows:

```
  slider.fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);
  }).fadeIn(400);
  console.log(index);
});
```

The problem is that if I have multiple button clicks, the image changes, but my fade animation happens like many times after, not just once to change the image.

Is there a way to stop the current animation, and proceed to fade in the next image? I just dont want multiply button clicks and then like 5 fade in's after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `stop()` method to achieve this. Providing `true` as the first parameter will also clear the queue of any following animations, which is useful if someone has repeatedly triggered the parent event. Try this:

```
slider.stop(true).fadeOut(400, function() {
  $(this).attr('src', images[index]);
}).fadeIn(400);
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop